# Loop through files in a given directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to loop through every file in a user specified directory.
Here's my code:

```
clear
echo "enter the directory path: \n"
read directory
for file in $directory; do
    echo $file
done
```

My input, e.g.: `/home/user/Downloads`

Output I get: `/home/user/Downloads`

If I use

```
clear
for file in *; do
    echo $file
done
```

It works, but it shows only the contenets of current directory

Comment: Do you want to loop through files recursively, or just the files in the given directory, not its children?

Comment: Just the files in the given directory, not the files from subdirectories

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you only want the files non-recursively in the current directory, combine what you have:

```
read -p 'Enter the directory path: ' directory
for file in "$directory"/*; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

If you want to loop recursively and you have bash 4, it's not much harder:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in "$directory"/**/*; do …
```

But if you only have bash 3, you'd be better off using `find`.

```
find "$directory"
```

Comment: For bash 3, you replace "shopt -s globstar" with "find "$directory""?

Comment: @kulan You can use `find` with any version of bash since it's an external command. And `find` is powerful in its own right, but if it's possible to do what you want in pure bash, you can avoid `forking`.

Comment: No, it's just that I'm beginning to learn bash scripting, I was unclear about what you said, so I wanted to make sure. Perhaps I would need it in the future.

Comment: @kulan you should definitely learn to [use `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind). It's complex, but extremely useful.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
dir="${GOL_HOME}/test_dir"
file="file_*.csv"
for file in `cd ${dir};ls -1 ${file}` ;do
   echo $file
done
```

Comment: best solution for me for file in `cd ./dist/libs;ls -1 ${file}` ;do
   echo $file
   cd "./dist/libs/$file"
   pwd
   cd ../../..
done

Answer (score -7):

You can write this script

```
 #!/bin/bash

clear
echo "enter the directory path: \n"
read directory
for file in $directory/*; do
    echo $file
done
```

Comment: This is the same as kojiro's answer.