# push all Dockerfiles to ACR using bash

Tags: bash, docker, shell, azure-devops, docker-repository

I'm trying to tag and push all my docker files into azure container repository by using bash script:

```
 path="./base-images"
dfname="test.azurecr.io"
for file in $path; do
 docker build . -t $dfname -f $file
 docker push $dfname/baseimage/
done
```

but I got an error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount173864107/base-images: is a directory
invalid reference format
```

Why does it write a different path? All my docker files are inside another folder (`base-images`).

Comment: Print the **$file** value and share the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for file in $path` is not giving you the individual files in that directory, which is what it looks like you're hoping for.  It is just going to assign the one value bash sees (`./base-images`) to `$file` and give you one iteration based on that.  That's why docker complains about `base-images: is a directory`: it is expecting a `Dockerfile` file, not a directory.

To get bash to loop through all of the files in that directory you need to [follow this answer from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408819/2002471) and start with

```
for file in "$path"/*; do
```

I would also suggest calling your `$path` variable `$dir` or `$directory` so you're not confusing other maintainers of this code with the `$PATH` builtin variable.

[Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would also tell you to put your variables in quotes such as:

```
docker build . -t "$dfname" -f "$file"
```